# Windows 10 does not shutdown, screen goes black and crashes if I force close it

Tags: windows-10, shutdown

It has been 13 hours since I pressed shut down and my computer is still running. This happened once more very recently and I had force shut-down my pc, and could not boot into windows again. I had to back up all my files using another OS on an external drive and format and restore everything and I don't want to do it again.
I searched for this issue on internet but all solutions involve changing windows or driver settings but I am stuck on a black screen. What can I do?

Additional information:

Computer is still connected to internet and I can login to my pc using other pc's in home on LAN, but see no file. Also peripherals like mouse behave as if the computer is running (for example, my mouse's dpi button normally doesn't respond when computer is sleeping or shut down, but now it does).
My mobo is Gigabyte (don't remember details and can't check since I am stuck on black screen) and I had no such issue with the same mobo for 8 years.

Edit: Also, I just realized, it happens after windows downloads updates. Don't know which updates tho.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem. Contacted Microsoft support and staff told me he/she knows this issue and is going to solve, so I force-rebooted the pc but this time it just booted fine. Maybe it has to do with the fact that I waited 15 hours, I don't know. In case yours doesn't boot after that, I will share the link and the steps.

**Download the version of windows that staff said has corrected the issue:**
https://software-download.microsoft.com/pr/Win10_1607_English_x64.iso?t=9206193e-af57-4bd4-b211-2c9f29933ea5&e=1474714493&h=108782915352c79b42bf2dea20e64b6c

**Follow these steps:**

> Repairing Windows 10 Using Installation Media
>   1. Plug the flash drive on the affected PC
>   2. Restart the PC
>   3. Once the manufacturer's logo appeared, press any keys.
>   4. Choose language, time and currency format and Keyboard input method.
>   5. When you see the Install Windows page, tap or click Repair your computer to start the Windows Recovery Environment.
>   6. In the Windows Recovery Environment, on the Choose an option screen, tap or click Troubleshoot.
>   7. Tap or click, advanced options and then click on Startup repair.
>   8. After this complete the repair and see if you are able to boot in to your computer

Here is the screenshot:
[support chat photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t9aEr.png)